# Encryption and decryption with AES Crypto-JS does not work as it should

Tags: javascript, html, encryption, aes, cryptojs

I have two difference html page, in the first one there is a form that on submit call a Javascript function to encrypt two different parameter after that these two parameter are sent in get to the second page, following the code of the first html page:

```
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Test Encrypt</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">


    /**
    Function to encrypt in AES tex
    **/
    function encText(plainText){

        var salt = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse("12345678");

        var password = "test";
        var keyBits = CryptoJS.PBKDF2(password, salt, {
            hasher: CryptoJS.algo.SHA1,
            keySize: 8,
            iterations: 2048
        });
        console.log(keyBits.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64));

        var iv = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse("dGVzdGFhYTAxMjM1Njc4OQ==");

        var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(plainText, keyBits, {
            iv: iv,
            padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7,
            mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC
        });

        //var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, key).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
        //var decrypted = encrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8)

        //var decrypted = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.stringify(encrypted);
        return encrypted.toString();


    }

    function formEncrypt(){
        var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
        var surname = document.getElementById("surname").value;

        var encName = encText(name);
        var encSurname = encText(surname);

        document.getElementById("name").value = encName;
        document.getElementById("surname").value = encSurname;

    }

    </script>
</head>


<form action="/decrypt.php"  method="get" name="myForm">
    name: <input type="text" name="name" id="name"><br>
    surname: <input type="text" name="surname" id="surname"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="formEncrypt()">
```

In the second page using a JavaScript function I try to  decipher the two parameters values, following the code of the second page:

```
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Decrypt</title>

    <?php
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
    echo 'var encName = \'' . base64_encode ( $_GET['name'] ). '\';';
    echo 'var encSurname = \'' . base64_encode ( $_GET['surname'] ) . '\';';
    echo '</script>';
    ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function decText(encryptedText){

            //var message = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(encryptedText);

            var salt = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse("12345678");

            var password = "test";
            var keyBits = CryptoJS.PBKDF2(password, salt, {
                hasher: CryptoJS.algo.SHA1,
                keySize: 8,
                iterations: 2048
            });
            console.log(keyBits.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64));

            var iv = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse("dGVzdGFhYTAxMjM1Njc4OQ==");

            var result = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(encryptedText), keyBits, {
                iv: iv,
                padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7,
                mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC
            });

            console.log(result.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));

            return result.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8)
        }

        function yoo(){
            console.log(encName);
            console.log(encSurname);
            var name = decText(encName);
            var surname = decText(encSurname);
            $('#pName').text(name);
            $('#pSurname').text(surname);
            //document.getElementById("pName").value += name;
            //document.getElementById("pSurname").value += surname;
        }


    </script>


</head>
<body>

    <p>Yooooo</p>

    <p id="pName"> </p>
    <p id="pSurname"> </p>

    <button onclick="yoo()">clearText</button>

</body>
```

But the result is always a blank string, I think there is a mistake but I don't find where.

Comment: You need to separate the HTML from the encryption for debugging. Find out which is in error and fix that. Debug, add print statements, reduce the problem. If the encryption is the issue provide sample input/intermediates/output. Nota bene: The IV needs to be **different** random bytes for each encryption, not does not need to be secret and can prefix the encrypted data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To decode a base64 string, pass the parsed object containing the word array to the stringify function for the Utf8 encoder. *i.e.* `CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.stringify(parsedObjectContainingWordArray)`

```
const encName = '<?php echo base64_encode($_POST["surname"]); ?>';
const encSurname = '<?php echo base64_encode($_POST["name"]); ?>';

function decText(encryptedText) {
  const salt = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse("12345678");
  const password = "test";
  const keyBits = CryptoJS.PBKDF2(password, salt, {
    hasher: CryptoJS.algo.SHA1,
    keySize: 8,
    iterations: 2048
  });
  const iv = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse("dGVzdGFhYTAxMjM1Njc4OQ==");
  const result = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(
    // This here is where the action is. If the wrong value gets passed,
    // result turns out to be empty string.
    CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.stringify(CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(encryptedText)),
    keyBits, {
      iv: iv,
      padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7,
      mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC
    }
  );

  return result.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8)
}

function yoo() {
  const nameNode = document.getElementById("pName");
  const surnameNode = document.getElementById("pSurname");
  nameNode.textContent = decText(encName);
  surnameNode.textContent = decText(encSurname);
}
```

Comment: Keysize is right in this context. _i.e_ `256/32` @zaph: [See how keySize is determined](https://github.com/sytelus/CryptoJS/blob/1d75606113b9446ee2bb56130709927eb3b3c45d/components/pbkdf2.js#L24)

Comment: Thanks! I tried to find the documentation but failed. But what a jerk thing for the developer(s) to do: specifying a key size in 32-bit words!

Comment: Thanks @OluwafemiSule for your answer, your solution works fine and the code you written more clear than mine ;).